# SQL QUERY ON MULTIPLES TABLES

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I'm new in Pure Sql I want to write this as Query

```
select items.* 
from items 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select sum(purchase_details.quantity) as total 
    from purchase_details 
    where (purchase_details.item_id=items.id)  
GROUP BY purchase_details.item_id) ABC
```

but this gives an error

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
    your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' 
    at line 1
```

i don't know why it's not working

Comment: Your query doesn't have `LIMIT` keyword (mentioned in the error message), can you post the full query?

Comment: That error doesn't correspond with your code. Rewrite your question, or your code, or your error ... or everything

Comment: You do not specify the field that you want to join is that the entire select stament? Additionally you only have sum field in your joined sub query? perhaps you need to add the Item_ID?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error here is that you need an `on`-clause for your `left join`. But the underlying conceptual problem is different: you cannot `join` with a *dependent subquery*.

You can fix your query like this:

```
select items.* 
from items 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  select item_id, sum(purchase_details.quantity) as total
  from purchase_details 
  GROUP BY purchase_details.item_id
) ABC on ABC.item_id = items.id;
```

This moved your inner `where`-condition (that would depend on `items.id`, which is not allowed, as it is out of scope) to the `on`-clause. Thus `item_id` is also added in the inner `select` (as it is needed outside).

A different way to write this would be

```
select items.*, 
   (select sum(purchase_details.quantity) 
    from purchase_details 
    where purchase_details.item_id=items.id) as total
from items;
```

Here you have a *dependent subquery*: the inner `where`-clause depends on the outer `items.id`. You do not need a `group by` anymore, as the `where`-condition already uses just the rows for that item. (And you can also only return at most one row in this context anyway.)

Both queries are equivalent, and can (if the optimizer finds that execution plan) internally actually be executed in exactly the same way (which is nothing you have to care about much though, as long as you provide appropriate indexes).

So in your case you can use both (and maybe check which one is faster); if you want to get additional information for that item, you should prefer the `left join`-version though, e.g. use

```
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  select item_id, 
    sum(purchase_details.quantity) as total,
    count(purchase_details.item_id) as cnt,
    max(purchase_details.quantity) as max_quantity_per_order,
    max(purchase_details.date) as latest_order,
    ...
  from purchase_details 
  GROUP BY purchase_details.item_id
) ABC on ABC.item_id = items.id;
```