# mysql sub-query cannot refer top table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have below table/column arrangement in MySQL database. (`FK` denotes foreign key)

```
SCHEDULES          [id(INT), next_date(DATE), notification_id(FK)]
NOTIFICATIONS      [id(INT), col_1(...), col_2(...), ...]
NOTIFICATION_LINES [id(INT), notification_id(FK), no_of_days(INT)]
```

**Relationships**:

*Multiple* `SCHEDULES` can have same `NOTIFICATION` (i.e n:1) whereas *One* `NOTIFICATION` can have multiple `NOTIFICATION_LINES`.

**Sample Data set**

```
SCHEDULES
-------------------------------------
| id | next_date  | notification_id |
-------------------------------------
| 1  | 07-08-2017 | N01             |
| 2  | 18-08-2017 | N01             |
-------------------------------------

NOTIFICATIONS
-----------------------
| id   | col_1  | col_2 |
-----------------------
| N01  | AA     | XX    |
| N02  | BB     | YY    |
-----------------------

NOTIFICATION_LINES
--------------------------------------
| id | notification_id | no_of_days |
--------------------------------------
| 1  | N01             | 14         |
| 2  | N01             | 5          |
-------------------------------------
```

**Requirement**:

I need to get the `MAX(no_of_days)` of a particular `SCHEDULE`.

I used below subquery:

```
SELECT sch.schedule_id, sch.notification_id, x.max_no_of_days
FROM   SCHEDULES sch, 
       (SELECT nt.notification_id, max(lt.no_of_days) AS max_no_of_days
        FROM   NOTIFICATION_LINES lt, NOTIFICATIONS nt 
        WHERE  lt.parent_id = nt.id 
        AND    nt.notification_id = sch.notification_id) x
WHERE  sch.notification_id = x.notification_id;
```

and it returns:

`#1054 - Unknown column 'sch.notification_rule' in 'where clause'`

If I substitute `sch.notification_rule` with a value, it returns correct result.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| id | schedule_id  | notification_id | max_no_of_days |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1            | N01             | 14             |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

If I cannot use parent query's alias, if anyone can let me know even a different SQL, I would be thankful to you.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks. I'll provide sqlfiddle example.

Comment: I see no notification_rule, only notification_id. I suspect, the most important reference you omitted to describe.

Comment: @aschoerk sorry, I had incorrectly typed the sql. I corrected it. It happened because, I altered the column names for SO but couldn't edit the SQL statement. I am going to add the sqlfiddle ref here in awhile... thanks

Comment: You cannot join with a dependent subquery. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501135/sql-query-on-multiples-tables/45505019#45505019). It is the same situation - except currently, you would have a `join` instead of a `left join`, although I think you actually want a `left join` too, to get results even if there is no notification.

Comment: Thanks everyone! @Strawberry While writing sqlfiddle, I thought I should change the design and I can now get what I want using `SCHEDULES` and `NOTIFICATION_LINES` tables. Thanks again.

Comment: Feel free to remove the question